# Accessing specific blocks of an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to access specific blocks of an array in matlab. Suppose my array A is of size 10x10.

Now I have two variables lets say

```
B = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6]
C = [1;2]
```

Then I want to access 1,2,3 rows of 1st col of A and 4,5,6 rows of 2nd col of A so that I get this result array of size 3x2. How can I do it efficiently in matlab without using for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Use following :

```
A(B(1,:),C(1,1))

A(B(1,:),C(2,1))
```

Finally 3x2 as

```
D = [A(B(1,:),C(1,1)) A(B(1,:),C(2,1))] ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done efficiently using a [linear index](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) built with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
result = A(bsxfun(@plus, B.', (C.'-1)*size(A,1)));
```

This approach works for accessing any number of columns of `A` (that is, for any number of rows in `B` and `C`).

*How it works*: `bsxfun` builds a linear index from the desired row and column indices, given respectively by `B` and `C`. Note that `C.'-1` is multiplied by `size(A,1)` because a new column in linear indexing means a step of `size(A,1)`. Transposition of matrices `B` and `C` is needed so that the result matrix has the desired shape.

Comment: @user12331 See edited answer. You should be familiar with the concept of linear indexing (follow link in my answer). It may be useful for you to observe the intermediate result `bsxfun(@plus, B.', (C.'-1)*size(A,1))` to grasp how this works